# Facebook: Quick Start for App Links Hosting API. Edit existing App links

Tags: applinks

In Facebook:
If I use the "Modify an existing App Link URL". How can I see my existing App Links or do I have to remember the links myself?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tool instead: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/applinkshost

It allows you to add/update/remove app links host urls.